# Main method problems in Black Scholes model

Tags: c#

This code gives the following error : `...\ConsoleApplication1.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.`

How can I solve this problem ?

```
namespace BlackScholes
{
    public class BS
    {
        public static double BlackScholes(double x)
        {
            double s = 100;
            double t = 1;
            double r = 0.10;
            double v = 0.10;
            double y = (float)Math.Pow(v, 2);
            double d1 = 0.0;
            double d2 = 0.0;
            double model = 0.0;


            d1 = ((float)Math.Log(s / x) + (r + 0.5 * y) * t) / v * (float)Math.Sqrt(t);
            d2 = d1 - v * (float)Math.Sqrt(t);

            model = s * cnd(d1) - x * (float)Math.Exp(-r * t) * cnd(d2);

            return model;
        }
        public static double cnd(double x)
        {
            double L = 0.0;
            double K = 0.0;
            double dCND = 0.0;
            const double a1 = 0.31938153;
            const double a2 = -0.356563782;
            const double a3 = 1.781477937;
            const double a4 = -1.821255978;
            const double a5 = 1.330274429;
            L = Math.Abs(x);
            K = 1.0 / (1.0 + 0.2316419 * L);
            dCND = 1.0 - 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2 * Convert.ToDouble(Math.PI.ToString())) *
            Math.Exp(-L * L / 2.0) * (a1 * K + a2 * K * K + a3 * Math.Pow(K, 3.0) +
            a4 * Math.Pow(K, 4.0) + a5 * Math.Pow(K, 5.0));
            if (x < 0)
            {
                return 1.0 - dCND;
            }
            else
            {
                return dCND;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want a library or executable program?

Comment: I want an executable program but I'm still beginner in c# programming.

Comment: you should define Main method. see the answer. otherwise you cant run the program. the program must start from somewhere and thats the `Main` method.

Comment: are these all the code in your Program? where do you call this methods?

Comment: Yes , all this code.

Comment: what to you want to do when program starts? this class is much like library... can you tell me what you want to do when program starts? you want to start from `BlackScholes` method and print `model` ?

Comment: I dont want library code , ı will not add an other program. I just want a simple consol application.

Comment: ok. simple console application gets some information from user. and outputs some result to the user. The program without input-output is useless. your code is correct (ignoring the Main method problem). but still you can add this empty Main method to your program. it will start but you will see nothing happens. its not clear for me what you want to get from this program.

Comment: I will use for europen stock option price. So , do you think how can ı add ' Main ' method in this code ?

Comment: see the edit. Is that what you want. see how i get number from user and print out the result calling method. you may need to do something else. i cant guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You removed the Main method. but The program always starts from `static Main` method.

```
public class BS
{
     static void Main() // this method is missing
     {
          //TODO : just an example. Do your main operations here. (Usually input/output)
          double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine(BlackScholes(x)); // outputs the result 
     }
    public static double BlackScholes(double x)
    {
        double s = 100;
        double t = 1;
        double r = 0.10;
        double v = 0.10;
        double y = (float)Math.Pow(v, 2);
        double d1 = 0.0;
        double d2 = 0.0;
        double model = 0.0;


        d1 = ((float)Math.Log(s / x) + (r + 0.5 * y) * t) / v * (float)Math.Sqrt(t);
        d2 = d1 - v * (float)Math.Sqrt(t);

        model = s * cnd(d1) - x * (float)Math.Exp(-r * t) * cnd(d2);

        return model;
    }
    public static double cnd(double x)
    {
        double L = 0.0;
        double K = 0.0;
        double dCND = 0.0;
        const double a1 = 0.31938153;
        const double a2 = -0.356563782;
        const double a3 = 1.781477937;
        const double a4 = -1.821255978;
        const double a5 = 1.330274429;
        L = Math.Abs(x);
        K = 1.0 / (1.0 + 0.2316419 * L);
        dCND = 1.0 - 1.0 / Math.Sqrt(2 * Convert.ToDouble(Math.PI.ToString())) *
        Math.Exp(-L * L / 2.0) * (a1 * K + a2 * K * K + a3 * Math.Pow(K, 3.0) +
        a4 * Math.Pow(K, 4.0) + a5 * Math.Pow(K, 5.0));
        if (x < 0)
        {
            return 1.0 - dCND;
        }
        else
        {
            return dCND;
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about [Main()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

If you are trying to make a library (`.dll`) then you must change your Output type to ClassLibrary. in Project settings

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class where are two method will help to calculate call and put price using Black Scholes formula.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OptionCalculater
{
    public class CallPutOptionPrice
    {
        double S, K, r, q, T, v, Call;
        public CallPutOptionPrice(string Is, string Ik, string Ir, string Iq, string It, string Iv)
        {
            S = double.Parse(Is);
            K = double.Parse(Ik);
            r = Math.Round(double.Parse(Ir) / 100, 4);
            q = double.Parse(Iq);
            T = Math.Round((double.Parse(It) - 1) / 365, 6);
            v = Math.Round(double.Parse(Iv) / 100, 4);
        }
        public string callOptionPrice()
        {
            double d1 = (Math.Log(S / K) + (r - q + v * v / 2.0) * T) / v / Math.Sqrt(T);
            double d2 = d1 - v * Math.Sqrt(T);

            double b0 = 0.2316419;
            double b1 = 0.319381530;
            double b2 = -0.356563782;
            double b3 = 1.781477937;
            double b4 = -1.821255978;
            double b5 = 1.330274429;

            double pi = Math.PI;
            double phid1 = Math.Exp(-d1 * d1 / 2.0) / Math.Sqrt(2.0 * pi);
            double td1, cd1;
            double Nd1 = 0.5;
            if (d1 > 0.0)
            {
                td1 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d1);
                Nd1 = 1.0 - phid1 * (b1 * td1 + b2 * Math.Pow(td1, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td1, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td1, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td1, 5));
            }
            else if (d1 < 0.0)
            {
                d1 = -d1;
                td1 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d1);
                cd1 = 1.0 - phid1 * (b1 * td1 + b2 * Math.Pow(td1, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td1, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td1, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td1, 5));
                Nd1 = 1.0 - cd1;
            }
            double phid2 = Math.Exp(-d2 * d2 / 2.0) / Math.Sqrt(2.0 * pi);
            double td2, cd2;
            double Nd2 = 0.5;
            if (d2 > 0.0)
            {
                td2 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d2);
                Nd2 = 1.0 - phid2 * (b1 * td2 + b2 * Math.Pow(td2, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td2, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td2, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td2, 5));
            }
            else if (d2 < 0.0)
            {
                d2 = -d2;
                td2 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d2);
                cd2 = 1.0 - phid2 * (b1 * td2 + b2 * Math.Pow(td2, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td2, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td2, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td2, 5));
                Nd2 = 1.0 - cd2;
            }
            Call = S * Math.Exp(-q * T) * Nd1 - K * Math.Exp(-r * T) * Nd2;
            return Call.ToString();
        }

        public string putOptionPrice()
        {
            double d1 = (Math.Log(S / K) + (r - q + v * v / 2.0) * T) / v / Math.Sqrt(T);
            double d2 = d1 - v * Math.Sqrt(T);

            d1 = -d1;
            d2 = -d2;

            double b0 = 0.2316419;
            double b1 = 0.319381530;
            double b2 = -0.356563782;
            double b3 = 1.781477937;
            double b4 = -1.821255978;
            double b5 = 1.330274429;

            double pi = Math.PI;
            double phid1 = Math.Exp(-d1 * d1 / 2.0) / Math.Sqrt(2.0 * pi);
            double td1, cd1;
            double Nd1 = 0.5;
            if (d1 > 0.0)
            {
                td1 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d1);
                Nd1 = 1.0 - phid1 * (b1 * td1 + b2 * Math.Pow(td1, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td1, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td1, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td1, 5));
            }
            else if (d1 < 0.0)
            {
                d1 = -d1;
                td1 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d1);
                cd1 = 1.0 - phid1 * (b1 * td1 + b2 * Math.Pow(td1, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td1, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td1, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td1, 5));
                Nd1 = 1.0 - cd1;
            }
            double phid2 = Math.Exp(-d2 * d2 / 2.0) / Math.Sqrt(2.0 * pi);
            double td2, cd2;
            double Nd2 = 0.5;
            if (d2 > 0.0)
            {
                td2 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d2);
                Nd2 = 1.0 - phid2 * (b1 * td2 + b2 * Math.Pow(td2, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td2, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td2, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td2, 5));
            }
            else if (d2 < 0.0)
            {
                d2 = -d2;
                td2 = 1.0 / (1.0 + b0 * d2);
                cd2 = 1.0 - phid2 * (b1 * td2 + b2 * Math.Pow(td2, 2) + b3 * Math.Pow(td2, 3) + b4 * Math.Pow(td2, 4) + b5 * Math.Pow(td2, 5));
                Nd2 = 1.0 - cd2;
            }

            Call = K * Math.Exp(-r * T) * Nd2 - S * Math.Exp(-q * T) * Nd1;
            return Call.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```